# how to find if groovy args contains a particular string

Tags: groovy

```
println args

println args.size()

println args.each{arg-> println arg}

println args.class

if (args.contains("Hello"))
    println "Found Hello"
```

when ran give following error:

```
[hello, somethingelse]
2
hello
somethingelse
[hello, somethingelse]
class [Ljava.lang.String;
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.
String;.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
[Hello]
```

why can I not do `contains`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `args` is `String[]` but not `List<String>`

You can use

```
if (args.grep('Hello'))
    println "Found Hello"
```

Comment: Please look at somewhat similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345795/check-a-lists-value-contains-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

That's because args is an array of String (just like in Java) and not a String, take a look at the result of:

```
print args.getClass()

>>class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Notice the **[L** notation.

A regular String would result in:

```
>>class java.lang.String
```

The Groovy containers do not have the contains() operation (String does), yet the java.lang.Object of Groovy SDK has the grep() operation (shown on the first reply).