# Check if a list's value contains in a string

Tags: groovy

I have a list `def vrs=["6.0","6.1","6.1.0"]` (versions) and I get a map in a function with this value `def test=[version:6.1 HotFix11]`.

How can I check whether `test`'s `version` value matches with the list `vrs`?

I tried this `vrs.each{ver-> println test.version.contains(ver)}` but it gives `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

**Update**

Turns out, there was something wrong with my code. I tried the test case in a small Groovy script and it works.

Here is the full code:

```
private Map params
private def root

private def nineBelow

XmlHandler(String xml)
{
    nineBelow=["6.0","6.1","6.1.0"]

    params=[:]
    root=new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
}
def getParams()
{
    if(root.product.version.size()>0)
    {
        params.version=root.product.version.text()
    }

    /*nineBelow.each {
        println params.version  //even this throws java.lang.StackOverflowError
        //println "$it , ${params.version}"
        //println ver.getClass()+", "+params.version.getClass()
         }*/

    println nineBelow.each{ver-> println params.version.contains(ver)}

    /*I need to check whether `params.version` matches with `nineBelow` list, so i'll check for condition here*/

    params
}
```

Another class which calls `getParams()`

```
static main(args) {

    String fileContents = new File('E://Projects/agent6.1.xml').text
    XmlHandler xm=new XmlHandler(fileContents)  

    def params=xm.getParams()
    println params
}
```

**Update**

Even `println nineBelow.each { println params.version}` gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

**More Update**

It worked only after the below code

```
def ver=params.version
    println nineBelow.each { println ver.contains(it) }
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an example that fails with some example xml?  I ask because this (which you say at the top of your question crashes) actually works:

```
def vrs=["6.0","6.1","6.1.0"]
def test=[ version:'6.1 HotFix11' ]

vrs.each { ver-> println test.version.contains( ver ) }
```

and prints:

```
false
true
false
```

But I cannot find a problem with your other code, as I don't know what `'E://Projects/agent6.1.xml'` contains...

Comment: I tried an example, which works perfectly fine too. But anyways the problem is resolved. see More Updates in my question

Comment: Can you please solve another [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346903/how-to-use-a-groovy-class-in-a-jsp-page)?

Comment: I was using wrong jar instead of `groovy-all-1.8.6.jar` i was using `groovy-1.8.6.jar` It solved my problem for the other question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code is as follows:

```
class XmlHandler {
    private Map params
    private def root

    private def nineBelow

    XmlHandler(String xml)
    {
        nineBelow=["6.0","6.1","6.1.0"]

        params=[:]
        root=new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
    }

    def getParams()
    {
        if(root.product.version.size()>0)
        {
            params.version=root.product.version.text()
        }

        nineBelow.each {
            println params.version  //even this throws java.lang.StackOverflowError
           //println "$it , ${params.version}"
           //println ver.getClass()+", "+params.version.getClass()
        }
   }
}

def doc = """
    <root>
        <product>
            <version>1.0</version>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </product>
</root>
"""

XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler(doc)
handler.getParams()
```

Therefore, in `println params.version` you are actually invoking `getParams().version` thereby entering in an endless recursive call.

Check [Groovy @ symbol before fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319403/groovy-symbol-before-fields). As *tim_yates* says there, ¿bug or feature?